# angular form not getting set to invalid on date below min value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-forms

I have an input field with type set to date.

```
<p>Form is valid : {{myForm.$valid}}</p>

<input type="date" ng-model="model.myDate" placeholder="yyyy-MM-dd" min="{{minDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}" max="{{maxDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}"  />
```

Using the popup calendar control the min date is locked accordingly but I can still type in the date or use the up/down pickers to go below the minimum date. I'm still OK with this, however the form doesn't set to invalid.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set valid min and max date (hardcode/data binding), it will lock that duration. You can't even access the dates beyond this range using up/down caret.

```
<form name="myForm">
  <input type="date" ng-model="model.myDate " placeholder="yyyy-MM-dd" 
   min="2013-01-01" max="2015-12-31" required  />
   <p>Form is valid : {{myForm.$valid}}</p>
</form>
```

Comment: I have this but the min value doesn't seem to be picked up. I'm using Chrome. The max value works!?